# Subset a dataframe according to multiple negative condition

Tags: r

I would like to subset a dataframe

```
> head(SH)

  V11       yr  mo dy
1 US009239 1941  2 14
2 US009239 1941  2 14
3 US009239 1941  2 14
4 US009239 1941  2 15
5 US009239 1941  2 15
6 US009239 1941  2 15
```

in this way

```
test <- subset(SH,SH$yr!=yrmin & SH$mo !=momin)
```

where

```
> unique(SH$yr)
[1] 1941 1940

> unique(SH$mo)
[1]  2  1 12

momin =2
yrmin =1941
```

Anyway, what I get is

```
unique(test$yr)
[1] 1940

> unique(test$mo)
[1] 12
```

meaning that the subset function does not consider together the 2 conditions.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post your dataframe? Use `dput(SH[1:25, ])`. Also are `yrmin = 1940` and `momin = 1`? It may be that whenever `SH$mo` is `2`, `SH$yr` is `1940`. If not, try `SH$yr!=yrmin | SH$mo !=momin`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine logical statements with boolean operators, and don't want to use standard evaluation i.e. `[`, then I suggest looking at the new package by Hadley `dplyr` e.g.

```
library(dplyr)

filter(iris, Sepal.Length != 4 & Sepal.Width != 4)

# or equivalently
filter(iris, Sepal.Length != 4, Sepal.Width != 4)
```

In fact, I suggest looking at `dplyr` anyway: it's awesome!